# OCaml type error for lists

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function that will combine all the elements in a list in OCaml. Simple enough, so far I have a working function:

```
let rec comAll (f : 'a -> 'a -> 'a) (r : 'a) (l : 'a list) : 'a =
  match l with [] -> r
  | hd::tl -> let comAll2 = comAll f r tl in f hd comAll2
;;
```

The First argument is a function, the second is a default value to return when/if the input list is empty, and the third argument is the list itself.

This function works as intended, except when I try to call it using another function, for example:

```
let inList (l : 'a list) (e : 'a) : bool = comAll (fun x y -> if x == e then true else y) false l ;;
```

which will pass as a function, returning `inList : bool list -> bool -> bool = <fun>` however, I want to instead have it return `inList : 'a list -> 'a -> bool = <fun>`

I have tried instead defining comAll as: `let rec comAll f r l =...` and that works, but I want to declare the function with explicit types.

Any help or guidance on what I am doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your parameter `f` to be of type `'a -> 'a -> 'a` but you want to pass a function of type `'a -> bool -> bool`. In other words, you want to have two different types. You should declare `f` to be of type `'a -> 'b -> 'b`. The rest will follow.

```
# let rec comAll (f : 'a -> 'b -> 'b) (r : 'b) (l : 'a list) : 'b =
  match l with [] -> r
  | hd::tl -> let comAll2 = comAll f r tl in f hd comAll2  ;;
val comAll : ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b = <fun>
# let inList (l : 'a list) (e : 'a) : bool =
      comAll (fun x y -> if x == e then true else y) false l;;
val inList : 'a list -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
```

Comment: Okay, but for the purposes of what I'm working on, is there a way to make it work with `'a -> 'a -> 'a`?

Comment: No, there isn't. You want to pass a function that isn't of type `'a -> 'a -> 'a`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help. I think I've got a grasp on it now